# Converting excell formulae to vba for flexibility in conceating multiple cell values into single cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in two columns whose range is variable and I need to get the values of these cells into two cells. I used an Excel formula, but as the range is variable, I don't find it reliable.

Suppose the data is in columns A and B as shown below and output cells are D1 and E1:

```
A              B                 C                                  D

AA            BB            AA,A,AAA,AAAA,DD               BB,B,BBB,BBBB,DD
A             B
AAA           BBB
AAAA          BBBB
DD            DD
```

Excel formulas:

```
D1 = (A1&","&A2&","&A3&","&A4&","&A5)

E1 = (B1&","&B2&","&B3&","&B4&","&B5)
```

Here the range is untill `5` but it's not fixed it can vary. The format is as mentioned in the formula.

Please help me out! If it's possible, I would like to have the VBA codes.

Comment: how do you determine how many cells you want to concatenate?

Comment: Like this: [Convert a column into a comma separated list](http://superuser.com/questions/240858/convert-a-column-into-a-comma-separated-list)

Answer (score 1):

Create an excel function in VBA with the below code:

```
Function myConCat(S As Range) As String

  Dim cell As Range
  Dim con As String
  Dim I As Integer

  I = 1

  For Each cell In S
      If I = 1 Then
          con = cell
      ElseIf cell <> "" Then
          con = con & ", " & cell
      End If

      I = I + 1
  Next cell

  myConCat = con
End Function
```

Then in cell C1, put:

```
 =myConCat(A1:A5)
```

And in D1, put

```
 =myConCat(B1:B5)
```

You can then change the cell range to whatever you like.

I got this from Shane Devinshere's post here: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/combine-text-from-multiple-cells-into-one-cell-a1-a2-a3.3858902/

So all credit goes to him.

Hope that this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can put the following code into a VBA module in your workbook and use the function `=ConcatRange(range)` on your workbook to achieve what you require

```
Function ConcatRange(rng As Range) As String

Dim output As String
Dim r As Range

For Each r In rng
    output = output & r & ", "
Next r

ConcatRange = Left(output, Len(output) - 2)

End Function
```

for example, use `=ConcatRange(A1:A5)` for cell `C1`